# Do Ohgi count as Combat Ninpo for purposes of the Bad Weather battlefield?

Tags: shinobigami

In the Shinobigami rulebook pg. 141 it says for the Bad Weather Battlefield:

> All Combat Ninpo ranges increase by 1.

Clearly this would apply to standard attack ninpo like Close Combat etc., but it is not clear whether ohgi were also considered "Combat Ninpo" or if they were a special type of attack that would not get the range increase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Ougi are not attacks, and are therefore not Combat Ninpō, and thus are not affected by the Bad Weather Battlefield effects.**

I happened to be reading [the Japanese errata for main rulebook](http://www.bouken.jp/pd/sg/sgkk_rule_modified.html) and noticed an entry that seems relevant to your question. It notes (emphasis added):

> 奥義の使用
>
> 奥義には指定特技が設定されています。そうした特技が使用不能になっていても、奥義の使用には影響しません。また、**奥義のなかには【クリティカルヒット】や【範囲攻撃】のように、一部が攻撃の処理に似ているものがありますが、これらは攻撃ではありません。**

The emphasized portion says (translation mine):

> Ougi with types like "Critical Hit" and "Area Attack" have resolution processes that resemble attacks; however, they are not attacks.

While this does not explicitly state an answer to your question, given that the only other form of attack described in the book is Ninpō, the intent here seems to be that Ougi are not Ninpō, and as a result, would not be affected things like the Bad Weather Battlefield that affect Combat Ninpō.